# React Option.js - Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an automated chart using react-chartjs-2 in react and for a second I added the `options: {legend: {display: false}}` and I started having this error, I removed the code from above and the error didn't disappear.

Anyone might have a clue?

```js
./node_modules/react-select/src/components/Option.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\HP\Desktop\myTable\my-app\node_modules\react-select\src\components\Option.js: 
Unexpected token, expected "," (3:14)

  1 | // @flow
  2 | /** @jsx jsx */
> 3 | import { type Node } from 'react';
    |               ^
  4 | import { jsx } from '@emotion/core';
  5 | 
  6 | import type { CommonProps, PropsWithStyles, InnerRef } from '../types';
```

This is my code if needed to help you get a better understanding.

```js
  render() {
    let alphabet = ['B','C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

    const data = {
      labels: [...this.state.rows.map(x => x.A)],
      datasets: alphabet.map(value => {
        let color = this.state.color[value] || this.state.color.DEFAULT,
        checkIfUndefined = () => {
          if (this.state.rows[0][value] === undefined) {
            return ''
          } else {return this.state.rows[0][value];}
        }
      return{
        label: this.state.rows[0][value],
        data: this.state.rows.map(x => x[value]),
        backgroundColor: `rgba(${color.r}, ${color.g}, ${color.b}, ${color.a})`
      }})
    };

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <ReactDataGrid
            columns={this.state.columns}
            rowGetter={i => this.state.rows[i]}
            rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
            onGridRowsUpdated={this.onGridRowsUpdated}
            enableCellSelect={true}
        />
        <button onClick={this.newRow}>New row</button>
        <Line data={data} />
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're importing Node incorrectly. You have to declare like this:

```js
import type {Node} from 'react';
```

Comment: Yes, the only thing inside the braces is a list of modules separated by commas.

Comment: I declared it like that but it still throws the same error, meanwhile it is followed by a red underline error which says `'import type' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8006)`